# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple, pandas read_html

Tags: python, pandas

So I have some code intended to read the html of a website, it does that fine-grabs exactly what I need. However, whenever I print out the results, I'm unable to specify the row/column to print.

Here's my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

url = 'https://rocketleague.tracker.network/rocket-league/distribution'

header = {
  "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.75 Safari/537.36",
  "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
}


r = requests.get(url, headers=header)
df = pd.read_html(r.text)

print(df)
```

However, as stated, when I try to specify a row, column-for instance:

print(df[1,3])

I get the error TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

Comment: @AnuragDabas I get the error TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list when trying that. Thanks for trying!

Comment: try `print(df[0])` because there is 1 list of dataframe in df variable

Comment: @AnuragDabas That just accomplishes the same thing as 'print(df)' in the original code.

Comment: No it doesn't and you can verify it by `print(type(df))` and `print(type(df[0]))`.......`df` is list and `df[0]` is dataframe

Comment: @AnuragDabas Then from print(df[0]) how would I go about specifying the row/column?

Comment: `df=df[0]`  then specify like you do normally for example `df['Division I']`

Answer (score 0):

- as per comments `read_html()` returns a list of data frames that correspond to each table in the HTML
- for this web-page there are two that are actually different columns from displayed page.  Used `concat()` to merge these
- then for demonstration purposes,  extracted **Tier** and **Players** encoded strings in **Tier / Players Tracked**
- then generated a graph similar to what you see on web page

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

url = 'https://rocketleague.tracker.network/rocket-league/distribution'

header = {
  "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.75 Safari/537.36",
  "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
}

r = requests.get(url, headers=header)
df = pd.read_html(r.text)
df = pd.concat(df)
df = df.join(df["Tier / Players Tracked"].str.extract(r"(?P<Tier>[A-Z,a-z, ]+)(?P<Players>[0-9,\,]+)"))
df["Players"] = pd.to_numeric(df["Players"].str.replace(",",""))
df.loc[df["Tier"].ne("Unranked ")].plot(kind="bar", x="Tier", y="Players")
```

#### output

[image]